# Laptop -> HD video file -> VGA output -> HDTV == HD quality viewing?

Tags: laptop, tv, hdtv, hdvideo

If I use a VGA cable to connect laptop to HDTV, will the HD video I have running on the laptop display in High Def on the TV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could certainly run it at HD resolution, assuming your TV and video card support HD resolutions. It wouldn't be quite as good as if you were using an HDMI or DVI cable, but the difference is probably negligible unless you have a really top-end TV.